# Represent hex string by two integers

Tags: string, hex

There are dynamic hex strings, for example:

```
8d9440d9d4
11074feb5fdcd6d50d3eb719a26d
ace234cceb43689d8107994a7fc5
beefb1b271c453b99fa5ef60
```

and I wonder, if it would be possible to use some smart algorithm to convert this into a **integer of max value of 65535**.

It is probably way too small of value to represent the stuff above, I actually have available two values with the same max, so maybe somehow it would be possible to split the string? If you multiple 65535 by 65535 you get 4294836225 - would that be of any help?

Comment: What is the approximate meaning of these strings?  Just to estimate its entropy.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff So we have encryption algorithm in place, the key gets split into several peaces and we need each piece represented by what I described above

Comment: You cannot encode that peaces into 32-bit values as number of possible hex strings are much more than 2^32

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Even if we add some restrictions ? For example the hex string would only limited length ?